# In CLion, what is a proper run configuration? I'm having trouble understanding what I should put for 'Executable'

Tags: configuration, cygwin, executable, clion

My run configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSJjF.png

My settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcEmF.png

I've tried googling for hours, I can't find an answer.

My compilations look like this:

C:\Users\me\CLionProjects\untitled\cmake-build-debug\untitled.exe

Process finished with exit code 127

Comment: Your *Run Configuration* is correct. CLion will specify executabe for yourself when you add `add_executable()` in your CMakeLists.txt. Your problem is that you are trying to run your executable from wrong environment. Does it executes well inside CLion (when you press `Shift+F10`) ?

Comment: Hello, I was able to fix it finally. I deleted cygwin and installed MinGW-w64 again and it worked. I think that Avast or Comodo Firewall was making it so that the compilation suites would not work.